# How to hide Value in array for Battleship game?

Tags: python, random

I writing a Battleship game, however I'm not sure on how to change the 1 in the first players grid to a 0, so that the player can not see where the ship is.

```
import random

# formatt to access certain grid point print (grid_1[1][2])

grid_1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0]]

row_random = random.randint(0,3)
column_random = random.randint(0,3)
ship_1 = grid_1[row_random][column_random] = 1 
# creates a random spot in the grid where the ship will be 

def Player_1():
 
  for i in grid_1:
    print (i)
    #loops through grid so the output is in row and column form 
  x = int(input("Enter row:"))
  y = int(input("Enter column:"))
  co_ordinates_1 = (grid_1[x][y])
  # user guses where the ship will be
  if co_ordinates_1 == 1:
    print("BATTLESHIP HIT")
  elif co_ordinates_1 != 1:
    print("You missed!")
  # shows the user if they hit the target or not
Player_1()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear please provide more details

Comment: You will likely need a lot more structure to accomplish this. Remember that in the actual game there are four grids - one for each player and one each for what they've tried. It's probably easiest if you, too, have multiple grids. Then you task is to check the right grid when making a guess, and marking a different grid with the result of that guess. That latter grid is what should be displayed.

Comment: @NathanielFord Thank you for the feedback I will apply this to my program.

Comment: Hi @DarrenPassoulas , it would be helpful if you could provide us with some more details in your question. It would be good if you could explain more about what the expected output should be and what the current result is with the code. As Nathaniel mentioned, you will likely need a more complex data structure to do this - i.e. multiple grids, one for tracking the player 1 ship and one for tracking the player 2 ship.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if a value is equal to 1 (ship). Here is the code below

```
for i in grid_1:

        row = i.copy()
        for j in range(0, 4):
            if row[j] == 1:
                row[j] = 0
        print(row)
```

This code loops through each item and checks if it equal to 1. If it is, then the value is set to 0. This should print out

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```